# Creating an Contact for Lync 2010 Manually

Tags: wpf, lync

I have the problem of trying to manually creating an Lync contact in C# code. And checkin if the person is available. But i can seemed to get it to work. I found some code that automaticly gets the contact from an list.

```
   var contact = (Contact)contactList.SelectedValue;

        if ((ContactAvailability)contact.GetContactInformation(ContactInformationType.Availability)
            != ContactAvailability.Offline)
        {
            _conversationManager.AddConversation();
        }
```

But i would like to remove the list and use an person that is stored in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are samples in MSDN that shows how to get contact by Uri, telephone number or other attributes (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh345270.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh378560.aspx)
They can help you